# Greyscale mouseover to color effect of logo does not work in FireFox

Tags: css, grayscale

I recently implemented some CSS code to have my logo start at a greyscale color and, when the user moves his mouse over it, the logo turns to color. It works fine in Chrome, but in FireFox the logo  is not visible until you mouse over it. Does anyone know how to fix this problem?

[image]

CSS:

```
#logos img {
filter: url('js/filters.svg#grayscale'); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(1); /* Webkit Nightlies & Google Chrome Canary */
opacity: .5;
padding: 20px;
}

#logos img:hover {
filter: none; /* Applies to FF + IE */
-webkit-filter: grayscale(0);
opacity: 1;
-webkit-transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
-o-transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
-moz-transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
transition: 0.3s all ease-in;
}
```

HTML:

```
<section style="z-index:1; background-color:#f5f5f5;">
    <section class="container">
        <center>
        <div id="logos" class="col-md-12">
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/dell_logo.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
        <!--<a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/centos_logo.png" alt="" title=""/></a>-->
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/endian_logo.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/ccsp_logo.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/bbb_logo.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
        <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="images/microsoft_logo.png" alt="" title=""/></a>
        </div>
        </center>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I know why this is happening, I'm not sure I know how to fix it.

```
filter: url('js/filters.svg#grayscale'); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
```

You are setting the CSS property `filter` to two values, that means the latter will be assigned, so the first line of this does not affect the value of `filter`.

My best guess would be to use `-moz-filter` for the Firefox one.

```
-moz-filter: url('js/filters.svg#grayscale'); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
     filter: gray; /* IE6-9 */
```

Also, I'm pretty sure you can do

```
-moz-filter: grayscale(1); /* Firefox 3.5+ */
```

as you did in `-webkit-filter`

Comment: Perfect. I simply forgot to add the -moz- declaration. Thanks, guys!

Answer (score 0):

If I load the page with Firebug enabled, I get the following error:

```
NetworkError: 404 Not Found - http://ogmda.com/si2s/js/filters.svg"
```

So, it simply can't find your SVG file.